# how to calculate the differance between each salary and min salary

Tags: sql-server

i'm using sql server 2008 rs1 and I have a problem with a query .
my table is named : employees 
table columns are : 
`first name , last name , job title , gender , date of birth and salary` .

The required : to display job title, employee name, and the difference between salary of the employee and minimum salary for the job

I try to solve it as this :

```
SELECT First_Name, Title ,Salary-min(Salary) AS (Differance) FROM Employees;
```

but this cause an error 
help me please 
thanks in advance

Comment: Which error? Can you specify the data type of Salary?

Comment: salary data type is numeric(10, 0)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that minimum salary is the minimum for all the employees you need to select the minimum from all employees and use;

```
SELECT 
  First_Name, 
  Title, 
  Salary - (SELECT MIN(SALARY) FROM Employees) As Difference 
FROM Employees
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Min(Salary) Differance
         FROM   Employees)
SELECT First_Name,
       Title,
       Salary - (SELECT * FROM   cte) AS Differance
FROM   Employees;
```

Comment: thank you Pradeep. But could you explain what is the ; with cte means and do ?

Comment: @haneenraida - It is just a temporary holder here to hold the minumum salary in the table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query to calculate the min-salary:

```
SELECT First_Name, Title ,Salary-(SELECT MIN(e2.Salary)
                                  FROM Employees e2) AS Difference 
FROM Employees
```

You don't need to be afraid that this is calculated for every row.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
;WITH cte(minimumSalray)
AS
(
    SELECT MIN(Salary) 
    FROM Employees
)
SELECT First_Name, Title ,Salary-cte.minimumSalray AS Differance 
FROM Employees,minimumSalary
```

Comment: thank you Kiran . But could you explain what is the ; with cte means and do ?

Comment: It is common table expression to get the minimum salary. It just like a temperary variable. Instead getting this for each record, we can use CTE.

Comment: If you're going to use a common table expression (new-ish in the history of things), let's not use old-style joins. In your case, it's a cross join (which isn't bad here since the CTE only emits one row), so spell it out as such.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have a SQL Server 2008 R2, just tried on SQL Server 2014.

```
SELECT First_Name, Title ,
    Salary-min(Salary) OVER() AS [Differance] 
FROM Employees;
```

If you want to get minimum salary of the same job, just query

```
SELECT First_Name, Title ,
    Salary-min(Salary) OVER(PARTITION BY Title) AS [Differance] 
FROM Employees;
```